# I got an error "500 Unrecognized command" when sendding a test email in redmine

Tags: smtp, redmine

I can send an email with the gmail smtp in Redmine. But when I use out smtp service, get the error: 500 Unrecognized command. There is a crontab to send email also use the same smtp service mail, but it work well.
The email config in configuration.yml like:

```
production:
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      address: "mail.topxia.net"
      port: 25
      authentication: :login
      domain: 'mail.topxia.net'
      user_name: 'user'
      password: 'mypassword'
```

run "telnet mail.topxia.net 25" in commond, the result is:

```
Trying 127.0.1.1...
Connected to topxia.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 howzhi.net ESMTP Haraka 1.2.1 ready
```

I don't what wrong with this! Anyone can help me ? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem on previous versions until I started using Postfix to send mail.
This allows me to send via Amazon SES(or any server) server using TLS.

My only config in Redmine is "delivery method: sendmail".

You may have reason for sticking with Redmine mechanism but I found my issues went away as soon as I used Postfix.

Couple of resources that may help:
http://www.linuxgurru.com/2010/05/how-to-setup-email-notification-on-redmine/
http://blog.duoconsulting.com/2012/01/30/using-amazons-ses-with-postfix-as-a-smarthost-forwarder/

I don't normally just offer an alternative as the only option, but in this case it's the only one I know, that works with minimum effort.